# What's the correct way to make a privately symbolicatable release build in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debug-information

What's the correct configuration to make a privately symbolicatable release build in Visual Studio? I want to generate and store a PDB file which would allow me to symbolicate crash dumps of the built executable, but to avoid embedding debug information in the executable itself which would allow an external user to observe symbols, e.g., function and variable names, without the PDB.

I'm used to the DWARF debugging format, which can either be embedded in an executable or be exported to a separate dSYM file, which seems to be the rough equivalent of a PDB; I'm not sure whether or not Visual Studio has the similar option of ever/sometimes embedding the debug information similarly or not in the executable, and if it does, what configuration options I need to turn on to make sure a release build doesn't embed this information.

Comment: If you're writing a PDB, you've already separated symbols, as I recall. C7 debugging compatibility would embed them in the final executable; a separate PDB will database them in their own file (which you should retain with your release bits as part of your build process for doing exactly what you're describing; debugging dumps from the field). You do NOT need to (and *should* not want to) ship the PDBs.

Comment: Expanding on @WhozCraig's comment, [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360.aspx) doesn't need symbol information to write a dump file. Symbols are resolved in your debugger, using your private PDB files.

Comment: @WhozCraig Of course, I have no intention to ship the PDBs. Just worried whether debug info could be embedded in actual executable.

Comment: @Danra It won't be if you use regular PDB output (use edit-and-continue if you like; I prefer not to). Our build processes retain all PDBs by having all projects output them to a single unified PDB folder separate from the build output (we retain .map files as well). All the projects dump their .pdb files into that location. When a build is placed into permanent retention (due to release), the PDBs are available for doing what you're describing: loading customer dumps and performing analysis. The customer has no symbols whatsoever.

Comment: You can decide, where the debug information is stored using the [/Z7, /Zi, /ZI (Debug Information Format)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc.aspx) compiler options. Note that compiler option [/Yd (Place Debug Information in Object File)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6bef4950.aspx) is deprecated.

Comment: @IInspectable Welcome to quote Microsoft's documentation as an answer since it clearly answers my question (specifically that with `/Zi` debug information is *not* embedded in the executable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [/Z7, /Zi, /ZI (Debug Information Format)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc.aspx) compiler options allow you to

> select the type of debugging information created for your program and whether this information is kept in object (.obj) files or in a program database (PDB).

Both `/Zi` as well as `/ZI` store debugging information in a program database. None of the information will be compiled into the final executable image.

Since you plan to use the debugging information for analyzing crash dumps of (presumably) release builds, make sure the [/Zo (Enhance Optimized Debugging)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn785163.aspx) compiler option is also enabled.